# ASP.NET CORE MVC - User in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to load a different JSON file in the Program class depending on the user role. I use windows authentication on the site and a basic table that stores the roles. I load the roles implementing IClaimsTransformation later on without any issue, but I'm not able to determine the requestor user at this earlier point...

I only get DOMAIN\MACHINE$ when I call System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Any idea about how to get the windows user there?  This is my Program.cs file:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var context = new ManualBookingContext("xxx"))
        {
            var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;


            User dbUser = context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.ToLower() == user.ToLower());

            if(dbUser != null)
                args = dbUser.UserRoles.Select(u => u.Role.Name).ToArray();
                            
        }

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    }
    
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {

        var sidebar = "sidebar.json";

        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            if (arg == "Admin")
                sidebar = "sidebar-admin.json";
        }
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile(sidebar,
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent` get the windows user for the current process. I.e. it seems like the asp.net server is running under the system user account `DOMAIN\MACHINE$`.

Also see this post:

> As a few others have mentioned, it is the computer account itself not the user account.
> ASP authentication errors like this are typically due to the computer account itself being passed as the authentication token instead of your user account.

https://serverfault.com/a/66700

To confirm this, you could try to run the application under the desired user and see if that gives the right username.

As for a fix, i've had a similar issue in the past and I had used WMI (windows management instrumentation) to get the currently logged on user. I've found this article which looks great, and contains some ready to use code:

```cs
public class Machine
{
    private static Object _classLocker = new Object();
    private static Machine _machine; 
 
    private Machine()
    {
    } // end private Machine()
 
    public static Machine getInstance()
    {
        if (_machine == null)
        {
            lock (_classLocker)
            {
                if (_machine == null)
                {
                    _machine = new Machine();
                }
            }
        }
        return _machine;
    } // end public static Machine getInstance()
 
    public String getUsername()
    {
        string username = null;
        try
        {
            // Define WMI scope to look for the Win32_ComputerSystem object
            ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
            ms.Connect();
 
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery
                    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, query);
 
            // This loop will only run at most once.
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
            {
                // Extract the username
                username = mo["UserName"].ToString();
            }
            // Remove the domain part from the username
            string[] usernameParts = username.Split('\\');
            // The username is contained in the last string portion.
            username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // The system currently has no users who are logged on
            // Set the username to "SYSTEM" to denote that
            username = "SYSTEM";
        }
        return username;
    } // end String getUsername()
} // end class Machine
```

https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-the-username-of-the-user-who-logged-onto-windows-from-windows-service/

Note that since you're in asp.net core you may need to install additional packages to use wmi, e.g.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/

Comment: Well, after this point, windows authentication through IIS is working fine, I can get the user name in controllers, helpers...it is only in this very first Program class where I cannot get the user that is making the request.

Comment: uuh ppft let me think here, could you check what `Environment.Username` gives? i believe this may have something to do with impersonation, and the code you're using now and Environment.Username could have different results because of impersonation but i don't remember what was what.